# Are WebGL using libraries much faster in pixel by pixel manipulation?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, webgl, pixi.js

## Hello Internet!

Playing around with code to make maybe cool but useless things is my hobby.

But as I do it more and more I want to make more complex things, and I think that **2d canvas context** just isn't enough anymore.

---

So that leads me to

### This question:

**Is using some of the WebGL 2d libraries such as Pixi.js make pixel by pixel manipulation faster?**

I know it might seem like a silly question and the answer might be obvious but it isn't for me.

I know that I would get huge frame improvement if trying to make a game, but let me try to give you an example of what I'm planning to create:

**Here's a snippet of one of my silly "projects"**

The code is total spaghetti, I didn't bother to make it tidy, but you can run it on full screen, and you might get an idea of what I'm planning to create.

```js
var width = 800;
var height = 400;
var canvas = document.getElementById("canv");
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
var data = imageData.data;

var input = "Math.tan((y - height/2) / (x - width/2))*(180/Math.PI)";
var calc;

function inputChanged(inp) {
  var x, y, i;
  try {
    eval("calc = function(x, y, i){ return " + inp.value + " }");
    inp.style.cssText = "border: 2px solid green";
    document.getElementById("errorLog").innerHTML = "";
    draw();
  } catch (e) {
    inp.style.cssText = "border: 2px solid red";
    document.getElementById("errorLog").innerHTML = e;
  }
}

function przyklad(str) {
  var polecenieElement = document.getElementById("polecenie");
  polecenieElement.value = str;
  inputChanged(polecenieElement);
}

function draw() {
  for (var index = 0; index < data.length; index += 4) {
    var i = index / 4;
    var y = Math.floor(i / width);
    var x = i - y * width;
    var equation = calc(x, y, i);
    var clr = hsl2rgb(equation, 100, 50);
    data[index] = clr.r;
    data[index + 1] = clr.g;
    data[index + 2] = clr.b;
    data[index + 3] = 255;
  }

  ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
}

function getColor(number) {
  var n = number % 510;
  return n > 255 ? (255 - (n - 255)) : n;
}

function hsl2rgb(h, s, l) {
  h = h % 360;
  var m1, m2, hue;
  var r, g, b
  s /= 100;
  l /= 100;
  if (s == 0)
    r = g = b = (l * 255);
  else {
    if (l <= 0.5)
      m2 = l * (s + 1);
    else
      m2 = l + s - l * s;
    m1 = l * 2 - m2;
    hue = h / 360;
    r = HueToRgb(m1, m2, hue + 1 / 3);
    g = HueToRgb(m1, m2, hue);
    b = HueToRgb(m1, m2, hue - 1 / 3);
  }
  return {
    r: r,
    g: g,
    b: b
  };
}

function HueToRgb(m1, m2, hue) {
  var v;
  if (hue < 0)
    hue += 1;
  else if (hue > 1)
    hue -= 1;
  if (6 * hue < 1)
    v = m1 + (m2 - m1) * hue * 6;
  else if (2 * hue < 1)
    v = m2;
  else if (3 * hue < 2)
    v = m1 + (m2 - m1) * (2 / 3 - hue) * 6;
  else
    v = m1;
  return 255 * v;
}
```

```css
#canv {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#polecenie {
  width: 400;
}

.przyklad {
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 400;
}

.przyklad:hover {
  background-color: #888;
}
```

```html
<body onload="inputChanged(document.getElementById('polecenie'));">
  <canvas id="canv"></canvas><br><br>
  <b>AVAILABLE VARIABLES: </b><br>
  <b>x, y</b> - X, Y coordinates of current pixel.<br>
  <b>i</b> - index of current pixel.<br>
  <b>width, height</b> - canvas width & height;<br><br> Rotation of hsl color in point (x,y) = <input id="polecenie" type="text" value="Math.tan((y - height/2) / (x - width/2))*(180/Math.PI)" oninput="inputChanged(this);"></input>
  <br><br><b id="errorLog" style="color: red;"></b><br> Cool examples:
  <div class="przyklad" onclick="przyklad(this.innerText);">Math.atan2((y - height/2),(x - width/2))*(180/Math.PI)</div>
  <div class="przyklad" onclick="przyklad(this.innerText);">Math.tan((y - height/2) / (x - width/2))*(180/Math.PI)</div>
  <div class="przyklad" onclick="przyklad(this.innerText);">Math.asin((y - height/2) / (x - width/2))*(180/Math.PI)</div>
  <div class="przyklad" onclick="przyklad(this.innerText);">x * y</div>
  <div class="przyklad" onclick="przyklad(this.innerText);">(width*height)/x*y;</div>
  <div class="przyklad" onclick="przyklad(this.innerText);">Math.random()*360</div>
  <div class="przyklad" onclick="przyklad(this.innerText);">Math.sqrt((x - width/2)*(x - width/2) + (y - height/2)*(y-height/2)) > 150 ? 100: Math.sqrt((x - width/2)*(x - width/2) + (y - height/2)*(y-height/2));</div>
  <div class="przyklad" onclick="przyklad(this.innerText);">((height*width) / (x+y)) + x%50</div>
  <div class="przyklad" onclick="przyklad(this.innerText);">Math.random()*30+((x
    < width/2.3 && y <=height/1.86) ? ((((y-6) % 35 < 18 && x % 45 < 20)&&(((y-6) % 35> 5 && x % 45 > 5))) ? i%3 == 0 ? 0 : (i%2 == 0 ? 240 : 120) : (i%3 == 200 ? 0 : (y%2 == 0 ? 240 : 280))) : (y % (height/6.5)
      < (height/(13)) ? i%3==0 ? 0 : (i%2==0 ? 240 : 0) : i%3==0 ? 0 : (x%2==0 ? 120 : 240)))</div>
</body>
```

### So...?

**Is it worth** to use some sort of library for this kind of applications?

Is the fps gain going to be worth spending the time learning API?

### Also as a side question:

**Could someone** recommend me something (some book, or a site) where I could learn how to make my code nice and clean?

---

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally have never been a fan of any form of JS libraries and frameworks. This is not to say they are bad, but libraries are cover all solutions, they tend to do a lot of vetting, and some are just full of bad code. This means there is a lot of extra code running (and some not so good code) that is not needed, impacting performance.

For beginners libraries provide a quick solution, but can lead to becoming dependent on a library. This means you do not learn the underlying API which can leave you at a disadvantage.

The best way to use a library is to open it up and take it appart. Remove what you will not use, change structures and functionality to suit your needs. In this way you optimise the library for your needs, learn how it is structured and also learn how to use the browser's API effectively by the libraries example (if it is a good library)

As for performance, if you are an experienced coder and understand javascript well, then avoid the library (but then you would know that already) as you will get more performance using the API directly.

If you are a medium coder then use the library as a template. And if you are a beginner then you should think about what you want, learn how to use the browser's API or abstract it away and concentrate on building your app and not worry too much about performance.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you mean by Pixel by Pixel manipulation.

I would say pixi.js itself would do nothing for pixel by pixel manipulation. That's not its point. On the other hand, using WebGL to do pixel by pixel manipulation should be faster in those cases where what you're trying to matches what [webgl can do](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-how-it-works.html)

As for your *silly projects* those looks like the kinds of things that are done on https://glslsandbox.com and https://shadertoy.com